# How to check next behaviorsubject value in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular7, angular8, behaviorsubject

I am trying to use BehaviorSubject next value in multiple components using service and I tried to see the next value of BehaviorSubject in the component but not coming in the console.Just i can see in the ui part like {{ interpolation }} but inside the console.log that value is not coming.What is the reason.If anyone knows please help to find solution.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-bootstrap4-navbar-ejavrr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontent%2Fcontent.component.ts

content.component.ts:

```
geteventMsg; 
  constructor(public commonservice:CommonService) {  } 
  ngOnInit(){  
    this.commonservice.currentMsg.subscribe(geteventMsg => this.geteventMsg = geteventMsg);  
    console.log("Current message=",this.geteventMsg);   //Not coming next value
  }
```

header.component.ts:

```
setMessage(){
      let count=this.cnt++;
      this.commonservice.changeMessage(count);  
   }
```

common.service.ts:

```
   private messageSrc = new BehaviorSubject(0);
   currentMsg = this.messageSrc.asObservable(); 
  
   changeMessage(message: number) {
    this.messageSrc.next(message);
   }
```

Comment: Please ensure that common.service.ts is singleton https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: @Timothy:I am new in angular so getting confusion..Can you update my stackblitz?

Comment: @Timothy: Not working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-bootstrap4-navbar-mcvtdw?file=src/app/content/content.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Simple :

```
 ngOnInit(){  
    this.commonservice.currentMsg.subscribe(geteventMsg => { 
      this.geteventMsg = geteventMsg;
      console.log("Current message=",this.geteventMsg);   
    });   
  }
```